# How to get the modulus of following complex number

Tags: symbolic, complex

I want to get the modulus of following

```
(1+(x+I*y)/2+(x+I*y)^2/12)/(1-(x+I*y)/2+(x+I*y)^2/12)
```

I use

```
Abs[(1+(x+I*y)/2+(x+I*y)^2/12)/(1-(x+I*y)/2+(x+I*y)^2/12)]
```

But I always get

```
                                    2
                 x + I y   (x + I y)
             1 + ------- + ----------
                    2          12
Out[52]= Abs[-------------------------]
                                     2
                 -x - I y   (x + I y)
             1 + -------- + ----------
                    2           12
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell M that all symbols are real:

```
expr = (1 + (x + I*y)/2 + (x + I*y)^2/12)/(1 - (x + I*y)/
      2 + (x + I*y)^2/12);
ComplexExpand@ Abs @expr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you explain more about `ComplexExand@ Abs @expr`? I am new user of Mathematica.

Comment: @Ben, the help https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html  really explains it well. Basically, if you type `Abs[x + I y]`, then M can't do `Sqrt[(x^2+y^2)]` since `x` and `y` themselves can be complex numbers, each with real and imaginary parts. If that was the case, then x^2 will contains a complex value in it. So someone came up with a function to tell M to assume all symbols are real.